# I have a page I only want accessed if someone clicks "submit" on a form. Why am I able to access the page when I type in the URL?

Tags: php, isset

I have a page named "booking.inc.php" inside a folder marked "Private". Here is the PHP code I wrote to prevent someone accessing the page by typing in the URL unless they click a button with the attribute "submit" and the name "book"...

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['book'])) {
echo "It works!"; 
}   
else {
header("location: ../index.php");
}
```

The HTML page is named "booking.php" and is not in the Private folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php require "header.php" ?>
<title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="private/booking.inc.php" method="post">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button type="submit" name="book">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter in some text into the form and click "submit", I just get a white page and nothing else. No echo statement that says, "It works!" Also, when I type in the path into the browser to get to booking.inc.php, I also just get a blank white page instead of being directed to index.php.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display_errors.  Must be a parse error that we don't see.  And what do you mean by _marked "Private"_?

Comment: Hi Michael! Can you specify what you mean by a folder "marked private"?

Comment: Hi, SvenTUM! Yes, so on my Desktop, I have a folder I arbitrarily named "Project". Inside Project, I have another folder named "Private", which is where I stored booking.inc.php. The booking.php file is inside Project and not in a subfolder. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I believe your php code is correct, but the permissions on your private folder are incorrect. You can move booking.inc.php to beside booking.php and try it.

Comment: Arash, I will give that a try, but isn't it generally considered smarter to have a file like booking.inc.php in a separate folder?

Comment: Arash, good news-- your recommendation worked!! Maybe I'll just stick the files in the same folder for now...

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for ? if someone try to access "booking.inc.php" directly the code will redirect them to another location.Use the code on the top of  "booking.inc.php".

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
// redirect them to another uri
header('location:../somefile.php');
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### "private" directory

The *private* directory you created is not private in any way. It is just a sub-directory. Therefor I recommend not choosing this name.

#### single template

You have all the options but you might consider not creating a new file at all. If you choose so you could just send the action to the same file and handle the request accordingly depending on if it's a `GET` of `POST` request. This would semantically handle the booking template. It could even allow you to render the page again, if some information was wrong and refill the form with the previously set values handling the error with grace.

### redirect

I'm not 100% on this matter, but the redirect might be fine; just that it does not work on your setup. As far as I know you might not receive any headers when using localhost.

If you put a `echo "You got blocked";` in there instead of the header it should work. There are other ways of redirection, but you should be fine on a dedicated web server.

### security

If you think this check will somehow secure your form submission, you're wrong. This check is not sufficient if the form is supposed to be secure.

As the name of the file is *booking.inc.php* I assume it might handle some users actions leading to a sale and should therefor be secured! If that is what you're actually asking the techniques you should have a look for are listed in the [prevention section of the CSRF Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention).